# BlueZ example gatt server

Tags: python, server, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

I'm learning about BlueZ and BLE. In the bluez/test directory there is a python 'example gatt server'. I've read the code and almost understood how it works, but something is not clear. For example there's this method which notifies when a characteristic's value changes (in this example is the battery level value):

```
    def notify_battery_level(self):
    if not self.notifying:
        return
    self.PropertiesChanged(
            GATT_CHRC_IFACE,
            { 'Value': [dbus.Byte(self.battery_lvl)] }, [])
```

The method PropertiesChanged is so defined:

```
@dbus.service.signal(DBUS_PROP_IFACE,
                     signature='sa{sv}as')
def PropertiesChanged(self, interface, changed, invalidated):
    pass
```

I'm starting advertising and running this example, then i'm using the BLE scanner app on my smartphone for reading the characteristic (the battery level in this case). Well, the self.battery_lvl is an integer number (24 for example), but on ble scanner as the value of characteristic i see "24 % battery level". The problem is that nowhere in the code is added '% battery level' to the self.battery_lvl (simply 24). So where are this additional informations added?
Sorry for my english. If you need additional informations please tell me

Comment: The "%" sign is added in the smartphone app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The battery level example uses the Bluetooth service adopted UUID (0x180F) and attribute format (Please see [this](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml)). As such, when the mobile phone app finds the service and sees the UUID, it will know that this is the battery service, and add the % when reading the value. This is a major advantage when using adopted services/characteristics vs custom ones, you can add intelligence at the remote end because the local end has a predefined format. Please note that this also applies to adopted heart rate service/characteristic (the app will immediately add bpm), adopted temperature service/characteristic (the app will immediately add (°C), and so on.

For a full list of adopted services and characteristics, please see these links:-

- [Adopted GATT Services](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services)
- [Adopted GATT Characteristics](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics)

For further reading about this subject:-

- [Bluetooth GATT: How to Design Custom Services and Characteristics](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/)

I hope this helps.